# Call LazyQuery Hook From A Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I am using a graphql query like this:

```
 const [loadUsers, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery);
```

If I use this in my code, the lazy query `loadUsers`works and also displays the results:

```
return (
    <div>
        <StyledSearchBar
          value={searchItem}
          onChange={value => {
            setSearchItem(value);
          }}
          onRequestSearch={() => loadUsers()}
        />
        {data &&
          data.users.nodes &&
          data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
            <li key={i}>
              Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
              Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
            </li>
          ))}
      )
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, if I change `onRequestSearch={() => loadUsers()}`to ````` onRequestSearch={() => ShowUsers()}```` , the console gives me `````Check```but there's no graphql query executed and no results are shown.

```
function ShowUsers() {
    console.log('Check');
    loadUsers();
    {data &&
      data.users.nodes &&
      data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
        <li key={i}>
          Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
          Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
        </li>
      ))}
```

Why is this so?

**Edit:**

This runs the mutation but doesn't load the users.

```
onRequestSearch={() => ShowUsers()}
```

```
 function ShowUsers() {
    console.log('Checkk');
    loadUsers();
    return (
      <div>
        <Typography>Checking</Typography>
        {data &&
          data.users.nodes &&
          data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
            <li key={i}>
              Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
              Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
            </li>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return JSX from within a handler function, you can however convert the mapped JSX to a component and pass on props to it

```
const [loadUsers, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery);
return (
    <div>
        <StyledSearchBar
          value={searchItem}
          onChange={value => {
            setSearchItem(value);
          }}
          onRequestSearch={() => loadUsers()}
        />
        <ShowUsers data={data}/>
      )
    </div>
  );
} 

function ShowUsers({data}) {
    console.log('Check');

    return data &&
      data.users.nodes &&
      data.users.nodes.map((c: any, i: any) => (
        <li key={i}>
          Id: {c.id}, First Name: {c.firstName}, Last Name: {c.lastName},
          Email: {c.email}, phoneNumber: {c.phoneNumber}
        </li>
      )
    )
}
```

Comment: I want to move the query itself to another function. Even with the return, it doesn't print the data. Edited the qs

Comment: @Jnl event handlers are not for printing, it can change state/save result to be used in following/forced (by state change) rerender - read BASIC react docs (event handling)!

Comment: As I said in. my answer you can't return JSX from within an event handler, you need to render the data as a component and pass props to it.  ShowUsers will only get rendered when there is data to show